# How do I verify if I am calling a service with the right paramether, when I want to ignore the rest paramethers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have `SomeService` class which has method `verify(Company company, Location location)`; `Location` is enum - `Location.EUROPE` and `Location.USA`. Based on the location I choose different email template, that is I have private method inside `SomeService`:

```
 private String chooseServiceResource(Location location){
    if(location.equals(Location.EUROPE))
      return "resourceEU";
    return "resourceUSA";
  }
```

inside the `someService(Company company, Location location)` I call `chooseServiceResource(location)` and select the right template string.

```
public void someService(Company company, Location location) {
    String name = company.getName();
    String info = company.getInfo();
    ....

    String resourcee = chooseResourceTemplate(location);

    String body = templateEngine.process(resource, content);
    ...
    //do something else and send the email
  }
```

`templateEngine` is injected `@Qualifier private TemplateEngine templateEngine;`

**UPDATE:**
Inside `EmailService` I have the following method:

```
public void setTemplateEngine(TemplateEngine templateEngine) {
    this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
  }
```

And I am injecting it the following way:

```
 @Autowired
  @Qualifier("textTemplateEngine")
  private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
```

Inside `EmailServiceTest` this used to be my setUp():

```
@Before
  public void setup() {
    ThymeleafConfig tc = new ThymeleafConfig();
    templateEngine = tc.templateEngine();

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    emailService.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
  }
```

Yes, I know that `templateEngine` is not a mock but an actual object, and hence the error on line `verify(templateEngine).process("templateEU", any(Content.class));`. But when I change it to a mock, I get `NullpointerException`.

**End Of the Update**

In my test, I want to test that when Location is Europe it will process `templateEU` and when location is USA it will process `templateEU`.

I tried the following:

```
@Test
  public void shouldCallTemplateEngineWithEuropeTemplate(){
    location = Location.EUROPE;

    //throws null pointer exception
    emailService.sendEmail(any(Person.class), location);

    verify(templateEngine).process("templateEU", any(Content.class));
  }
```

But it complains that I am mocking the `Person` parameter. At this particular test, I don't care which `Person` object I am sending, I only care about the `Location` enum.

Comment: You can't call a method with "any person". You need to call it with a specific person. Then, based on that specific person, you can check that process() has been called with eq("templateEU"), and with any() content.

Comment: argument matchers are used when arranging or asserting member calls. They are not used as arguments when exercising the member under test'

Comment: The message tells exactly what the problem is. You can only verify if a method has been called with expected arguments on a mock, not on a regular object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

argument matchers are used when arranging or asserting member calls on mocked dependencies.

They are not used/passed as arguments when exercising the member under test and will actually pass the default value of the type, which in this case would be *null*. Hence the null reference exception when

```
String name = person.getName();
```

is called.

Instead, create an instance of the parameter and pass that to the subject under test.

```
//Arrange
location = Location.EUROPE;
Person person = new Person();

//Act
emailService.sendEmail(person, location);

//Assert
//...
```

or just mock the class and pass that instead to avoid null reference errors

```
//Arrange
location = Location.EUROPE;
Person person = mock(Person.class);

//Act
emailService.sendEmail(person, location);

//Assert
//...
```

making sure to setup any member calls on `Person` that would cause issues if not configured.

As for the template issue, you would should mock the template so that the unit test is truly an isolated test.

```
@Before
public void setup() {    
    templateEngine = mock(TemplateEngine.class); //Use a mock

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    emailService.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
}
```

And

```
verify(templateEngine).process("templateEU", any(Content.class));
```

behaves as intended.